# Slow and smooth drawing lines python matplotlib

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, lines

I'm using matplotlib for drawing graphs such as smooth lines. it is not problem to draw for me, but I have problems with animations.

```
import numpy as np
import random as random
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import animation
```

So, i have array, such as:

```
a = [0,1,2,4,5,8,9,12,14,18,22,17,30,37,29,45]
```

And I need to draw it smooth point-to-point.
Now I have this strings:

```
for i in range(len(a)-1):
    desty = np.append(desty,np.linspace(a[i],a[i+1],n))
    destx = np.append(destx,np.linspace(i,i+1,n))
```

that allows me to draw lines without problems (and animations :))

the full code:

```
# First set up the figure, the axis, and the plot element we want to animate
fig = plt.figure()
ax = plt.axes(xlim=(0, 50), ylim=(0, 50))
line, = ax.plot([], [], lw=2)
global x
global y
global n
global a
n=5
a = [0,1,2,4,5,8,9,12,14,18,22,17,30,37,29,45]

global desty,destx
desty = np.linspace(0,0,n)
destx = np.linspace(0,0,n)
for i in range(len(a)-1):
    desty = np.append(desty,np.linspace(a[i],a[i+1],n))
    destx = np.append(destx,np.linspace(i,i+1,n))
# initialization function: plot the background of each frame
def init():
    line.set_data([], [])
    return line,
# animation function.  This is called sequentially
def animate(i):
    global destx
    global desty
    x=destx
    y=desty
    line.set_data(x, y)
    return line,

# call the animator.  blit=True means only re-draw the parts that have changed.
anim = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, init_func=init,
                               frames=200, interval=20, blit=True)
plt.show()
```

Allows me to draw it only, but how can i draw it slow and smooth point to point?

I'm using python 2.7, centos 7.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can slim your plotting routine down to:

```
import numpy as np
import random as random
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import animation
# First set up the figure, the axis, and the plot element we want to animate
fig = plt.figure()
ax = plt.axes(xlim=(0, 50), ylim=(0, 50))
line, = ax.plot([], [], lw=2)

n=5
a = [0,1,2,4,5,8,9,12,14,18,22,17,30,37,29,45]

x = []
y = []

# initialization function: plot the background of each frame
def init():
    line.set_data([], [])
    return line,

# animation function.  This is called sequentially
def animate(i):
    x.append(np.linspace(i,i+1,n))
    y.append(np.linspace(a[i],a[i+1],n))
    line.set_data(x,y)

    return line,

# call the animator.  blit=True means only re-draw the parts that have changed.
anim = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, np.arange(0,len(a)-1) ,init_func=init, 
                               interval=200, blit=True, repeat=False)

plt.show()
```

Things to note:

- You don't require `global` variables for this to work
- You don't want to set up `x` and `y` outside of the animation but inside for the plot to develop (in your case you had the complete `x` and `y` set up so that the animation would only plot the entire graph)
- You need to pass an interable to `animate` (the `i`); this is the third input to `FuncAnimation` - `np.arange(0,len(a)-1)`.
- set `repeat=False` to stop after one run and to avoid 'closing' the curve
- I increased `interval` to make the plot develop slower

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `i` in your animate function, otherwise it just plots the same thing over and over, which is what you see.

```
import numpy as np
import random as random
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import animation

# First set up the figure, the axis, and the plot element we want to animate
fig = plt.figure()
ax = plt.axes(xlim=(0, 50), ylim=(0, 50))
line, = ax.plot([], [], lw=2)
global x
global y
global n
global a
n=5
a = [0,1,2,4,5,8,9,12,14,18,22,17,30,37,29,45]

global desty,destx
desty = np.linspace(0,0,n)
destx = np.linspace(0,0,n)
plot_me_x = []
plot_me_y = []
for i in range(len(a)-1):
    desty = np.append(desty, np.linspace(a[i],a[i+1],n))
    destx = np.append(destx, np.linspace(i,i+1,n))
    plot_me_x.append(np.array(destx))   # keep a copy of the intermediaries to plot later
    plot_me_y.append(np.array(desty))
# initialization function: plot the background of each frame
def init():
    line.set_data([], [])
    return line,
# animation function.  This is called sequentially
def animate(i):
    global destx
    global desty
    x=plot_me_x[i]
    y=plot_me_y[i]
    line.set_data(x, y)
    return line,

# call the animator.  blit=True means only re-draw the parts that have changed.
anim = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, init_func=init,
                               frames=len(a)-1, interval=20, blit=True)
plt.show()
```

For the plot to look different at each animation, `i` must index something that looks different at each iteration.  Although `desty` and `destx` are appended to gradually in the iteration that builds them, the final result is not this gradual build but a single thing, so you need to save the intermediaries of this build.  I did this with `plot_me_x` and `y`.

I wrote this answer with minimal changes to the OP's code to make it clear where the error was.  Overall, the changes that @Schorsch made lead to an overall cleaner approach (eg, with no globals).