# matplotlib, make smooth graph line

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am having trouble making the line connecting the points on my graph smooth. It seems to be more difficult because i am running an animated graph, all the examples I've seen online are for static graphs. I tried following this interpolation example but I cant seem to get it working. Any matplotlib gurus out there? Here is the code for the graph.

```
import psutil
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.animation as animation
from collections import deque


fig = plt.figure()
ax = plt.axes(xlim=(0, 200), ylim=(0, 100))
line, = ax.plot([],[])

y_list = deque([-1]*200)
x_list = deque(np.arange(200,0,-1))


def init():
    line.set_data([],[])
    return line,


def animate(i):
    y_list.pop()
    y_list.appendleft(psutil.cpu_percent(None,False))
    line.set_data(x_list,y_list)
    return line,

anim = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, init_func=init,
                           frames=200, interval=100, blit=True)

plt.show()
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Slow and smooth drawing lines python matplotlib](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27385619/slow-and-smooth-drawing-lines-python-matplotlib)

Comment: @MikeJSChoi Not a duplicate. In this question here, 'smooth' refers to smoothing of the line on the screen, while in the linked question 'smooth' refers to the transition in the animation.

Comment: @HexxNine What is "this interpolation example"? Can you link to it? You would also need to say what exactly you mean by smooth line? A straight line, showing the mean or a curved line? In how far do other examples of interpolation not work for you? Where exactly is the problem?

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest here is the link I was refering to, I thought I put it above guess I forgot :P https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/tutorial/interpolate.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are different kinds of smoothings. We may think about a line showing the mean, or a filtering function or a spline. I implemented all three methods below.

```
import psutil
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.animation as animation
from collections import deque

import scipy.ndimage.filters
import scipy.interpolate


fig = plt.figure()
ax = plt.axes(xlim=(0, 200), ylim=(0, 100))
line, = ax.plot([],[], color="b", label="cpu")
mean_line, = ax.plot([],[], linestyle="--", color="k",label="mean")
filter_line, = ax.plot([],[], linewidth=2, color="r", label="gauss filter")
interp_line, = ax.plot([],[], linewidth=1.5, color="purple", label="spline")

plt.legend()
y_list = deque([-1]*200)
x_list = deque(np.arange(200,0,-1))


def init():
    line.set_data([],[])
    return line,


def animate(i):
    y_list.pop()
    y_list.appendleft(psutil.cpu_percent(None,False))
    line.set_data(x_list,y_list)
    x = np.array(x_list)
    y = np.array(y_list)
    filtered = scipy.ndimage.filters.gaussian_filter1d(y, sigma=4)

    mean_line.set_data(x, np.ones_like(x)*y.mean())
    filter_line.set_data(x,filtered)
    try:
        tck = scipy.interpolate.splrep(x[::-1], y[::-1], s=50000)
        interpolated = scipy.interpolate.splev(x[::-1], tck, der=0)
        interp_line.set_data(x,interpolated[::-1])
    except:
        pass

    return line,filter_line,mean_line,interp_line,

anim = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, init_func=init,
                           frames=200, interval=100, blit=True)

plt.show()
```

[image]